# Application stops working after receiving results from another app

Tags: android

App1 has textFields, after pressing button values from those fields are sent to App2.

App2 sums those values and send results to App1, which then puts it to textView.

Problem is that my app breaks in this function which is supposed to update TextViews:

```
private void handleResult(Intent result) {

    TextView resultText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ResultText);
    TextView operationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.OperationText);

    operationText.setText(result.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT));
    resultText.setText(String.valueOf(result.getIntExtra("value", 0)));
}
```

**set.Text line's are the problem**

How should I properly return values from App2 so that I can set them to TextView of App1?

**App1**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final int UNIQUE_KEY = 777;
    private static final String PACKAGE = "com.example.student.projekt5add";
    private static final String CLASS = "com.example.student.projekt5add.MainActivity";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == UNIQUE_KEY && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            handleResult(data);

        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }

    private void handleResult(Intent result) {

        TextView resultText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ResultText);
        TextView operationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.OperationText);

        operationText.setText(result.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT));
        resultText.setText(String.valueOf(result.getIntExtra("value", 0)));
    }

    public void run(View view) {
        Intent sendIntent = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(PACKAGE);
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        sendIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(PACKAGE, CLASS));
        sendIntent.putExtra("EXTRA_GATHERED_DATA", gatherData());
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        startActivityForResult(sendIntent, UNIQUE_KEY);
    }

    private int[] gatherData() {
        TextView arg1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.arg1);
        TextView arg2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.arg2);
        return new int[]{Integer.parseInt(nullCheck(arg1.getText().toString())),
                Integer.parseInt(nullCheck(arg2.getText().toString()))};

    }

    private String nullCheck(String txt) {
        return txt.equals("") ? "0" : txt;
    }


    private void showToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**App2:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final String operation="addition";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        showToast("Starting "+operation+" subactivity");
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final int[] data = intent.getIntArrayExtra("EXTRA_GATHERED_DATA");
        if(data[0]==0 && data[1]==0)
        {
            showToast("no arguments");
            finish();
            return;
        }
        showToast("arguments: "+data[0]+", "+data[1]);
        Intent result =new Intent("com.example.student.projek5");
        result.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, operation);
        result.putExtra("value", handle(data));
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
        finish();
    }

    private int handle(int[] data)
    {
        return data[0]+data[1];
    }
    private void showToast(String message)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send the String operation value from app2 to app1 you need to send it as a key-value pair in the putExtra().

Instead of this:

```
result.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, operation);
```

try this:

```
result.putExtra("OperationKey", operation);
```

And in app1, to get the intent extra you could try this:

```
Intent extra = getIntent();
operationValue = extra.getExtras().get("OperationKey").toString;
```

Make operationValue a global string variable and where you want to set that as the text you simply put: setText(operationValue);

That might work.

Comment: I tried your method but I still get 'Projek5 keeps stopping", was I supposed to put Intent extra and operation value lines in App1 HandleResult function?

Comment: Btw when I try to see the contents of received 'data' with toast its value is null... :(

Comment: If you are trying to send data from app2 to app1 the putExtra I suggested should replace the line I identified in app2. To get the data in app1 you could write a short method on its own or you could put it in your handleResult method. I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish I guess, but if you are trying to send a string of characters from app2 to app1, I would try something similar to what I wrote